# How to aggregate on different cases in native sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my input.

```
| poNum      | poLineNbr | poLineQty | recvEaQty | evTypeCd | cnfrmSeqNbr | localDebitCredit | cnfrmQty | 
|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------|-------------|------------------|----------| 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 57        | 6        |             | H                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 336       | 6        |             | H                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      |           |          | LA          |                  | 66       | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      |           |          | LA          |                  | 32       | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 78        | 1        |             | S                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      |           |          | LA          |                  | 56       | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 72        | 1        |             | S                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 1         | 1        |             | H                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      | 17        | 1        |             | H                |          | 
| 3000773357 | 360       | 2520      |           |          | LA          |                  | 4        |
```

---

This is the logic provided to me.

For each combination of poNum and poLineNbr, get the quantity as described below. Each poNum and poLineNbr have a unique poLineQty.

#### Case 1:

When cnfrmQty > 0 and cnfrmSeqNbr = LA, ie, if *any* record exists for a particular combination of poNum, poLineNbr which has cnfrmQty > 0 and cnfrmSeqNbr = LA, then use that.

Calculation to do now for case 1 is:

`Qty = poLineQty - sum(cnfrmQty) + sum(recvEaQty where evTypeCd = 1 and localDebitCredit = H)`

sum(recvEaQty...) condition does not depend on what the cfrmSeqNbr is.

#### Case 2:

If there are **no** records for a particular combination of poNum, poLineNbr which has cnfrmQty > 0 and cnfrmSeqNbr = LA, then do the following.

`Qty = poLineQty - sum(recvEaQty where evTypeCd = 1 and localDebitCredit = S) + sum(recvEaQty where evTypeCd = 1 and localDebitCredit = H)`

#### Case 3:

When cnfmQty = 0 and total(recvEaQty where evTypeCd = 1) = 0, then do the following.

`Qty = poLineQty`

---

What I have done so far:

```
SELECT
    PO.poNum,
    PO.poLineNbr,
    (
        MIN(PO.poLineQty) -
        (
        SUM(CASE WHEN PO.cnfrmSeqNbr = 'LA' THEN PO.cnfrmQty ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN PO.evTypeCd = 1 AND PO.localDebitCredit = 'S' THEN PO.recvEaQty ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN PO.evTypeCd = 1 AND PO.localDebitCredit = 'H' THEN PO.recvEaQty ELSE 0 END)
        )
    ) AS Qty
FROM mytable AS PO
GROUP BY PO.poNum, PO.poLineNbr
```

---

I don't have an expected output, only the logic. I prefer solution in plain SQL, nothing vendor specific. CTE/Views etc are not allowed.

[SQL Fiddle for data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oySuGAVVrNLkNF5n1iQjSZ/0)

Comment: What is the problem with your current query and why don't you have any expected output?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the query should not use `evTypeCd = S` in the conditions given. I always use it. I should not use it when `cnfrmQty > 0`. No I don't have an expected output. This query is a part of a bigger process which I am doing.

Comment: So if anyone wants to help you there is no way they can know if they have the correct solution?

Comment: I apologize for the situation. If I knew I would share

Comment: How do you know it isn't working now if you have no output to test? if final output is wrong, how do you know that this part of the process is the issue? have you run this section of script against the database or a test one and compared the output vs expected output?

Comment: @ChrisCarroll I have been told by the person who provides the logic, that the output is wrong. He is a SAP person, does not know or understand SQL is what he says. I can ask once again maybe for an expected output. Other than that I am helpless too. I apologize.

Comment: I can't see you finding an answer without having a little actual output Vs expected output. If it were me and someone in my job told me something was wrong and that I needed to fix it, I would tell (not ask) them that if they want me to even investigate let alone fix, then they need to show me examples of why they think it isn't working correctly and to provide me with actual vs expected examples. Don't always assume the reporter is 100% correct, they might be mistaken and no issue exist, I'm not saying that is the case here but you need samples to assess that.

Comment: All that said, I just want to point out that your question was very well laid out, and other than the actual vs expected sample outputs, you had all details. Good structured questions are much easier to deal with. (don't want to seem completely negative)

Comment: @ChrisCarroll I can understand your comment. This is my first job, so I am not exactly taken seriously as a fresh grad when I say I am right. I cross checked with what I am supposed to get, in the table which I have the data, and yes you are right, the query written is right. It works. I also found the discrepancy in the logic they have provided. They did an unnecessary JOIN/FILTER which resulted in 0 records to be given out. From how I understand it, they find the logic *wrong* because SQL is declarative and not imperative. I will see if I can make them understand. Else... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ChrisCarroll Do I close the question? If so then how?

Comment: no problem, and just to clarify I wasn't trying to appear harsh, more just making the point that you cannot test something yourself before you are given actual vs expected data from your customer. Anyway, glad to hear it is solved. If it were an issue with your script I would say to answer your own question as it is good for someone with similar issue in future, but if it was a non issue as you say, then there is a "close" or "delete" option at the bottom of your question that you can click. best of luck with any future endeavors.

Comment: @ChrisCarroll you didn't come off harsh :) I understood the point you made. I make the same argument to the people assigning me this too. Anw, thank you.